# Replace spaces characters by a hard tab in a 6 GB file on Linux

Tags: linux, replace, sed, awk, vi

I have a vi command that replaces spaces characters by a hard tab:

```
     vi myfile.txt
       : # To go to the last line 
          1,$s/ /\t/g   # Then I type in this to replace spaces by a tab
```

How can I do it with [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) or [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)?

Comment: Not really related, but are you sure you want to replace every space with a tab character? Ususally it makes sense to replace every 2 or every 4 spaces with a tab if it's for formatting.

Comment: @madkitty- I'm a little interested. Is this 6GB file pure text?

Comment: It is a 6Gb file of pure text that should be organized in four columns for later on insertion in a MySQL table. Problem has been solved but if you come up with a better idea let me know :) Thnkx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you strictly want `sed`/`awk`, `tr` is the best option for it:

```
tr ' ' '\t'  < inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: oh thanks I'm trying tr right now one of our file, will let you if the indentation is more consistent. Thkx :)

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same thing works with `sed`, just use a real tab instead of `\t`:

```
$ sed 's/ /  /g' < input_file > output_file
# a tab ---^^
```

If you're doing this from the bash command line then you'll need to do a <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> pair to get a tab.

Comment: wait .. Do I have to type in  `$ sed 's/ /\t/g'` And that will work ? ^^ I don't need to open the file with an editor first? (like vi) or should I write the name of the file somewhere in the syntax?~~~~~~

Comment: @madkitty: "sed" stands for "stream editor" so you can stream data through it without having to load the whole thing into memory. I added a little update that might clarify things.

Comment: Ha~~~~~~now I understand THanks XD ^^ ~~~~~

Comment: Alright I just did it but the indenation is unconsistent..I can't seem to have the same result with vi ... Another solution maybe?

Comment: Oh and what do you mean by doing Ctrl-V Tab pair to get a tab ? Does that replace \t ?

Comment: @madkitty: Are you trying to change all lines or just the last line?

Comment: @madkitty: Hit Ctrl-V and then Tab, that will get a raw tab into the command, without the Ctrl-V, bash will try to interpret the Tab as a command completion.

Comment: I'm trying to change all lines and make it look like for columns so I can insert this later in a MySQL table.

Comment: @madkitty you need a script to do that. Why not changing the script?

Comment: Just a note, this might be kinda dangerous if there are spaces that should not be indented. Should all spaces be indented or just the beginning ones? If the latter, use `s/^ / /g` instead

Comment: @tjameson : all spaces :) It's a data file of 6Gb with consistent data.

Comment: @mu is too short : Do you ship your pies in Korea? That looks damn good ㅠ.ㅠ Thanks for you help, I just sent the output file to MysQL and it worked like a charm without warnings ^^

Comment: @madkitty: I only hand deliver my pies (strawberry/kiwi this time of year) still warm from the oven, sorry :)

Comment: @mu is too short : life is unfair lol Thankx for your help :)